# Old Software Licensing Question Delete or Reopen Dispute

Tags: discussion, specific-question

## Question

This question has 3 delete votes and 3 reopen votes:

- [LGPL, MIT, or Apache - differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/749461/456814).

It shouldn't be reopened because it's not about programming, but about software licensing, which is specifically stated as [on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) at [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

However, the question is also way too old to migrate...or is it? **How should this dispute be resolved? Deletion, historical lock, or migration?**

Note that it's not like it's hard to find licensing information from googling around for other sources, like [ChooseALicense.com](http://choosealicense.com/).

## Related

1. [Are licensing questions on- or off-topic on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70444/163250).
2. [Where can I ask about Software Licenses/Licensing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165980/163250).
3. [Which Stack Exchange site is most appropriate for asking software licensing related questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197296/163250).

Comment: Meh, the top two answers are just links, the top one is even broken. No historical value there. Let the community delete it.

Comment: Delete it immediately